# Is there fuser -k <PID> analogue for Mac OS?

Tags: macos, bash

I want to kill process that runs at some port. In ubuntu I used fuser -k 8000/tcp. What is the Mac OS way?

I found out this way:

```
lsof -i tcp:8000
kill -9
```

But it's very long. I need one short command like fuser

Thanx

Comment: lsof -i :8000 tcp:8000 + kill -9. But that are two non-short commands. I wanna one short.

Comment: I don't know if apple uses a bash shell, but if that is the case the question is relevant here..

Comment: But this question already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168392/shell-script-to-kill-the-process-listening-on-port-3000)

Comment: Mac OS X does use `bash`, but that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: `fuser` exists on very old versions of macOS. For example it's located in `/usr/bin` on `Yosemite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2023 I'm doing it this way:

`~/.local/bin/killport` (don't forget `chmod +x`)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "Port not specified"
else
    greparray=$(lsof -i tcp:$1 | grep -Eo "\s(\d{5})\s")
    for pid in $greparray
    do
        kill -9 $pid
        echo $pid
    done
fi
```

call it:

```
killport 8000
```

Answer (score 6):

Save this in some file that is in your `PATH`, call it `kill-server` for example. Make sure to `chmod +x` on it.

```
#! /bin/bash

lsof -i tcp:8000 | grep -v PID | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Then invoke it with `kill-server` or whatever you decided to call it. This is about as short as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217722/497885 to write a  script is an option.

Since `grep` and `awk` are used to extract the PID from `lsof` one can simply add the `-t` option.

So a shorter version would be:

```bash
lsof -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill
```